# Sizes for Android Backgrounds

Tags: android, android-activity, background

Ok, so I find generally that everyone will reference the Android Dev when the question is pretaining to background Images in an Android application. All I can find in the the Dev article is:

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

Does that mean I just convert dp tp pixels when I am creating each seperate drawable?
For instance 960dp is 1920px.

Answer (score 0):

You could have any of the next solutions:

1. really put each image in each density bucket. this will result in better precision of the pixels, but will make your app larger.
2. put one large image into either drawable-xhdpi or drawable-xxhdpi folders. rest of the densities will automatically adapt.
3. if the background is simple enough, use either a 9-patch or an xml drawable.

in fact, those solutions are valid for each image you face, and not just backgrounds.

in any case, do remember that having a background for the entire screen takes a lot of memory (can reach 3 MB for just a background, depends on the screen resolution).